# How to Unexpand an expanded UITableView Cell?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I'm expanding my cell via:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if(selectedRow && indexPath.row == selectedRow.row) {
        tableView.scrollEnabled = NO;
        return 480;
    }
    return 250;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    selectedRow = indexPath;
    [tableView beginUpdates];
    [tableView endUpdates];

    CGFloat height = 250.0f;//cell height
    tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, height * indexPath.row, 0);

   [tableView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, (indexPath.row * height) )animated:YES];

}
```

It works fine, whenever I select a cell, it do expands, but I couldn't figure out how to bring it back to its original height. Any thoughts?

Comment: Try `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:` with `selectedRow = nil`. Btw where you want to bring it back to its original height?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if(selectedRow && indexPath.row == selectedRow.row) {
        tableView.scrollEnabled = NO;
        return 480;
    }
    tableView.scrollEnabled = YES;
    return 250;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    CGFloat height = 250.0f;
    if (selectedRow && indexPath.row == selectedRow.row) {
        NSIndexPath *index = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:selectedRow.row inSection:selectedRow.section];
        selectedRow = nil;
        [tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[index] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];

        tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0);
        [tableView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, 0 )animated:NO];

    } else {
        selectedRow = indexPath;
        [tableView beginUpdates];
        [tableView endUpdates];

        tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, height * indexPath.row, 0);
        [tableView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, (indexPath.row * height) )animated:NO];
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Works fine, by the way I edited my Question, I added a code for inset and offset. So that when I clicked a cell, it will go on top position. Works fine, How can I bring it back to it's former position when I unexpanded it?

Comment: You can do the actions for shrinking the cell in the if statement and the actions for expanding the cell inside the else part.

Comment: Yup, it's working fine (expanding and shrinking is working fine now). Everytime I select a cell, I put it on Top Position First before I expand it. So when it came from the bottom part, when I shrink it, It stays at the top always. What I want is to bring it back to its original position. Can you help? Thanks

Comment: Works fine! Great, But hey, I have a UIView on top of My TableView which serve as my Fake NavigationBar (Its height is 50), I just notice that when I shrink the expanded cell, It goes back now near to its original position. Just about 50 points away, maybe same size of the Fake NavBar, I've tried editing your code on the contentInset and contentOffset but I could not do the right thing. Where do you think should I do the adjustments? Thank you very much!

Comment: It would be better if you ask your doubt as a question. It will help you to find more interesting and simpler answers from other users also.

Answer (score 1):

Try This :

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{    
        if(selectedRow.row == indexPath.row)
              selectedRow = nil;
        else
              selectedRow = indexPath;
        [tableView beginUpdates];
        [tableView endUpdates];

        [tableView reloadData];   
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Works fine, by the way I edited my Question, I added a code for inset and offset. So that when I clicked a cell, it will go on top position. Works fine, How can I bring it back to it's former position when I unexpanded it?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to add a custom property like `isExpanded` in your tableView datasource object and switch that property based on selection and return height according to this value.

For ex: In your `heightForRowAtIndexPath` method, you could have somthing like this.

```
if(yourCustomCell.isExpanded == true){
    return 480;
}
else{
    return 250;
}
```

In `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method, just set or unset this property.

```
yourCustomCell.isExpanded = !yourCustomCell.isExpanded
[tableView reloadData]; //Which will call heightForRow and then assign new height based on the property value.
```

Now if you dont have a custom cell object, then I think you can make use of cell's `isSelected` property.

I haven't tried these, but I guess this should work.