# Bring back Selected UITableViewCell to original position

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

This question of mine is in connection to my other question, here's the link:

[How to Unexpand an expanded UITableView Cell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22500462/how-to-unexpand-an-expanded-uitableview-cell/22500928)?

Well, expanding and shrinking of cell have been resolved already in the previous post. By the way, this is how it works;

Every time I select a cell, I put in at the top most position of the tableview first before I expand it, the expanded size covers the whole screen. It shrinks well (meaning it goes back to its original height), but after shrinking it is located in the top most position of the tableview because I put it there before I expanded it. What I wanted also is to bring the expanded cell to its original position upon shrinking it. (Meaning, If it is located at the bottom before expanding it, it should me placed back to that position upon shrinking it).

Thanks Guys!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calculating and setting `contentInset` and `contentOffset`, instead you can use saved values. It should work well if datasource isn't changed between the cell scaling in and out, otherwise it's up to you to tune the values.

Comment: yup..you can save the content offset value before expanding the cell and the use the saved value to again set the contentoffset of table.

Comment: can you show me some example? you can use my code on my previous post. Thanks!

Comment: @Josh, by doing it yourself you'll improve understanding of the process: add instance variables or properties to the view controller that manages the table, save the offset&inset values before you change them when expanding the cell and reapply when shrinking.

Comment: Hi thanks, been able to do it, I just save the contentOffset value, no need for the contentInset value to be saved. Thanks again, I've voted up your answer and verified it also.